# MSAccess - highlight query selection text in output

Tags: ms-access, text, highlight

I'd like to have the text which I use as a selection criteria in a query to be highlighted in the query list in MS Access. Is this possible or just a pipe dream?

Comment: You could go to a lot of trouble and use HTML or such like, otherwise, not that I know of.